# Writing a Robocopy Script With a Username And a Password

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a script that send a copy of the files that exist in a certain source to a certain destination using a username and a password.

I am putting the username and the password after creating the user on the server but it is still giving "logon failed: wrong username or bad password".

Please can you give me a help. My code is stated below. Is the ipc$ related to the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Code: msg * /time:0 /w Please close your outlook and all your MS documents

```
     net use \\server\ipc$ /user:username password

     robocopy source destination /mir /w:1 /r:1
```